# I'm using mybb, how can I find the top 5 threads that has the most readers currently?

Tags: mysql, sql, forum, mybb

I'm using [MyBB](http://mybb.com), I want to show on my website homepage the threads that has the most readers **currently**.

I'm assuming I have to query the session table but I'm not sure how should I do it

The mysql result I need, should look something like:

```
-------------------------
|title          | count |
-------------------------
|thread a title | 1234  |
|thread b title | 913   |
|thread c title | 678   |
|another  title | 593   |
|different title| 550   |
-------------------------
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What is the `session` table like?

Comment: MyBB has a `prefix_sessions` table which store all sessions of current visitors and their location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tested that on my board, I think this is what you need:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, subject as title
FROM `mybb_sessions`,`mybb_threads`
WHERE location1 = tid
GROUP BY `location1`
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```